# How to deploy a Ruby on Rails backend API with React to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have a Ruby on Rails v5.2 application that serves to a React project. There are both in different folder projects, the React project is not located in the same project as in the Rails project. My client wants me to use Heroku to deploy this project to production.

I've been searching how to deploy my Ruby on Rails and React project to Heroku. Unfortunately, I have only been able to find how to do so with both Rails and React in the same project, which caused me a bit of confusion how to deploy both Rails and React to one Heroku application.

Since my Rails application is a project and my React is another, I've been thinking about creating an application for each project in Heroku. The thing is, I don't think this is a good practice, since I might have a stage environment and a production environment in the future. I'm sure there must be a way to deploy my Rails and React project in one Heroku application.

How can I deploy a Rails and React project in one Heroku application if they're located on different project folders?

Do I need a configuration like a procfile or a webpack?

I was using before DigitalOcean with Ngnix and Puma, and I was running a build script like so in my React project:

```
"build-prod": "dotenv -e .env.production react-scripts build && cd build/static/css && rm *.map && cd ../js && rm *.map && cd ../../.. && rm -rf app_dist && mv build app_dist"
```

Then I  deployed it like this:

```
"deploy-prod": "scp -r app_dist/ user@117.89.99.118:/home/deploy/rails_api_backend/shared/public/"
```

With my Rails application I was using Capistrano to make my deployments to Digital Ocean. But, now I need to move to Heroku.

Comment: doesn't your react project give you a javascript file in the end? One option would be to just get a minified version of that file and add it to your asset pipeline and you're off to the races. You can use gulp / webpack to help you here. Or you could include your react project within your rails project and use the webpacker gem to take care of it all for you. With Heroku it's easy: add the node and ruby buildbacks and you can easily handle it

Comment: If your frontend is a SPA that can run off a static HTML file and a JS file then jamming it inside your rails heroku app might not be the solution. Heroku is relatively expensive to scale and your SPA just really needs to served by something that can serve up static pages really fast - which any webserver can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to deploy just the React application as a stand alone project to Heroku, you'll need a small server like Express.js.

app.js =>

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});
// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Just pop that app.js in your project folder at the top level and then deploy to Heroku (after you `yarn build` your app for production).

This is exactly what we're doing.  There is literally just a single route - the GET "/" route, that will route everything to the main page of the React app.  React router should take over from there.

Heroku wants a server-process for an application - it's not meant as a platform for static sites - but you can effectively make it such a platform by simply giving it a server process as in the above.  Then Heroku will happily 'npm start' your app on a free web dyno, and you'll be able to scale it up to paid dynos if you wish.

You'll also need a package.json file that includes express and has a `build` script - the one we use is:

```
"build": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true npm install"
```

Make sure you have your environment variables connected in Heroku also - the app.js above includes `process.env.PORT` to declare what port you want the server listening on - you may or may not want this, just be aware if you copy / paste.

Comment: I appreciate your response @tgmerritt! So this means I dont need to apps in heroku? One for my Rails Api backend and another for my React front end? With this approach I can only have 1 heroku app? I Appreciate your help man!

Comment: @KenSánchez No actually this method requires two apps - one for the front-end and one for the Rails API backend.  I think this is very good practice actually, because it decouples dependencies and you can freely deploy an update to the front or back without affecting the other.  By deploying both together, you're basically creating a single monolithic application, which is an anti-pattern in modern web dev.  You could host the React portion entirely in an S3 bucket if you wanted, but you asked for a Heroku solution.

Comment: what a very awesome question. Thank you very much for your support :D